# VB.NET: WYSIWYG page maker tutorial

Tags: html, vb.net, editor, wysiwyg

I have a course work for which I have to make a (as advanced as possible) WYSIWYG web page editor in VB.NET (2010). It should have a visual editor with drag-drop support for several elements such as anchors, images, tables etc., and it should generate HTML based on that structure.

I don't know where to begin though.. I have some experience with vb.net, I made a tabbed notepad vaguely following a tutorial, but I don't know how to make this drag-drop thingy in a richtextbox.

I've searched for a tutorial, but most of them are just too simple - a text editor with browser control rendering the HTML.. I found one really nice and advanced, but it's in german :-|

So, if anyone knows any resources / tutorials I could use to start things I'll appreciate it.

Comment: [German's not so hard!](http://german.stackexchange.com/) :)

Comment: Hehe, maybe.. but in a 90 minute video tutorial.. it is!

Comment: Could you post the link to this tutorial, maybe it helps us to better know what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't start with a richtextbox. Do you want to realize it in WPF or Forms (I would recommend WPF)?

In WPF there is relative simple a Drag-And-Drop behavior for elements (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms742859.aspx).

I would start with some simple elements (e.g. TextBoxes) and drag-drop them from some sort of toolbox onto a grid with fixed columns and rows (and later use a canvas). And then generate the HTML-Code from that.

Comment: Interesting idea.. I am not familiar with WPF neither is my teacher (I think) hehe, I though maybe I could use `IHTMLDocument2` to enable "editable mode" in a browser control..? Other than that my idea was too about drag-drop from a toolbox as you said, but if I am to go with it I suppose drag-drop wont work..

Answer (score 0):

In general, most of the WYSIWYG browser based editors are written in Javascript using an editable DIV.

A good example is tinymce:

http://www.tinymce.com/

Download, including full source code, is available here:

http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php

Comment: Who said anything about browsers? Look at the title, I need Visual Basic .NET tutorial.

Comment: The standard richtextbox control lacks the 'richness' to render HTML. If you want to roll your own, you could do worse than look at the 
the factory method pattern. 
http://www.oodesign.com/factory-method-pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use CKEditor. Its one of the best WYSIWYG editor i have worked with. Its highly customizable and opensource.

Given below is the URL for the website:
http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: I don't need an editor, I need a toturial on how to MAKE such editor in vb.net.

Comment: CKEditor (previously known as FCKEditor) is an opensource. You can get the source code for the control if you want. That will give you idea how to develop it.